# mp4-h264 video encoding (Media Foundation) fails on windows 7

Tags: c++, video, ms-media-foundation

I have code (taken from MSDN) that performs encoding of input AVI file to the output mp4 file (H264) with Media Foundation SDK. And it works perfect in Windows 10, but it hangs in infinite loop in Windows 7. After killing the application I can see output mp4 file with always the same size 32kb.

After few hours of debugging I found out that problem is in SetTopology() function that called in order to set topology on the Media Session. As result it calls session's callback method Invoke(IMFAsyncResult *pResult) with IMFMediaEvent that returns "-1072868846" value from it's GetStatus() method. I could not find any information what does that value mean and how can I fix that problem.

Original idea source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819476(v=vs.85).aspx

This is my cpp file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8d78059532a9a07913e2f8b836276d21

I compiled this in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: OK, the value is `0xC00D5212` aka `MF_E_TOPO_CODEC_NOT_FOUND` "No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content."

Comment: Tnx! The problem seems to be in input avi file. But I couldn't understand why?

Comment: Hi, what format of data is stored in avi file? I think that H264 encoder does not support that video format. Try test your Windows 7 by `MFTEnumEx` function - set input type from avi file and output type `H264` - research https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388652(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is how I generated my input avi file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1186fd86f18ef06096ec5334e4567c9

Comment: From your code I see that your avi has `opts.fccHandler = mmioFOURCC('D', 'I', 'B', ' ');` - I think that there is a problem with this format - check type of video format from `Source` MF_MT_SUBTYPE - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700208(v=vs.85).aspx  in MF code - it can need add colour converter manually in your code.